# Cryptographic accelerator and .NET

Tags: .net, cryptography, hardware-acceleration

Does .NET detect and use Hardware Cryptographic Accelerator for its cryptography operations (the way that it detects GPU and uses it for graphic operations)?

If not, what managed library do you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET is pretty large.

In Microsoft .NET, under Windows, you'll find types named:

- `*Managed`, e.g. `SHA1Managed` that are fully managed implementations. There **won't** be any hardware acceleration on them;
- `*CryptoServiceProvider`, e.g. `SHA1CryptoServiceManager` that will use CryptoAPI (native) code. **If** the native CSP has hardware acceleration then you'll get it.
- on newer frameworks versions, `*CNG` ([Cryptography Next Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). That's the replacement for CryptoAPI - same rules applies (if the native code can use hardware acceleration you'll get it).

In Mono, all platforms, you'll have fully managed implementations (whatever the name of the type) by *default*.

Now, in both (MS and Mono), cases you can also use your own (or a third party) implementation. That can even be totally transparent to your application when you use [`CryptoConfig.CreateFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig.createfromname.aspx) (directly or indirectly, e.g. `SHA1.Create`) and your `machine.config` file includes a reference to the alternative implementation. This allow you (or anyone else) to add (or replace) any implementation with another (including hardware accelerated) implementation.

Note: version 4.0 of the framework makes this even easier with the new [`AddAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig.addalgorithm.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Some HSMs (Hardware Security Module) come with extra provider implementations for [CAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [CNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). All of them usually come with a PKCS#11 driver (C-based).

Modern hardware will replace your default CNG providers with their custom implementation, practically resulting in the kind of auto-detection you asked for.

For HSMs that do not support this, you will either have to register the providers manually, or in the worst case, if no custom provider is offered, you will have to interface to PKCS#11 manually or use something like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pkcs11net/).

Answer (score 1):

Some hardware vendors manage to replace default SChannel and other providers with their own. If they do, then .NET would use replacements instead of stock providers. But there's no way to automatically detect and use cryptographic hardware.

Most accelerators are usable via PKCS#11 interface. In general, you can use our SecureBlackbox which will use such accelerators via PKCS#11, but you would have to "manually" specify the PKCS#11 DLL to call (autodetection is not possible as such DLLs are not registered in system).